# Decoding socket.io based websocket payload

Tags: encoding, websocket, socket.io, wireshark, packet-capture

I have a socket.io server and during testing I captured all live traffic with wireshark. The server switched protocol to WebSocket and I have been getting this sort of packets (this is at the websocket layer):

```
WebSocket
    1... .... = Fin: True
    .100 .... = Reserved: 0x4
    .... 0001 = Opcode: Text (1)
    1... .... = Mask: True
    .000 1000 = Payload length: 8
    Masking-Key: 435cfdf7
    Masked payload
    Payload
Line-based text data
    2*(\312OJ\005\000
```

I understand that the websocket data from client to server is masked, but what exactly does the line based text data mean and how can I decode it back into readable plaintext? The traffic isn't encrypted so I don't really understand how it works.